# Postgres find types used in procedures and user-defined functions

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to get the list of user-defined Types & Domains that are used in all the stored procedures and user-defined functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not easily, because the body of functions is stored as a string. One would have to parse that, which is particularly difficult, as there are so many procedural languages in PostgreSQL.

You could perform a substring search in the source code, but that is notoriously unreliable.

Comment: Thank you, just curious....'pg_depend' table do not have any information regarding procedure/function dependant objects?

Comment: No, not for the types used only in the function body.